# Rails Active Storage & AWS S3 : How to attach image to model through seeds.rb and then store it in S3 private bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

For a school project, I'm working on a Rails app which "sells" pics of kittens. I picked 10 pictures of cats online, they are currently on my computer. I'm using Postgresql for the DB. I have a class/model `Item` which represents the kitten photos.

What I'm looking for is a way to, when generating fake data through `seeds.rb` loops, attaching a kitten photo to each `Item` class/model, which will be then stored to an AWS S3 bucket that is already created (it's called *catz-temple*). I have my two access and secret S3 keys on a `.env` file, I already have modified my `storage.yml` file like so :

```
amazon:
    service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
    secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
    region: eu-central-1
    bucket: catz-temple
```

I found out there was a gem called `aws-sdk-ruby`, but I just can't find out what approach I should have on this topic.

For now, I just put my bucket in public access and take each bucket photos' urls, but there's no API and secure approach into this...

Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting by follow the guides for [configuring ActiveStorage and S3](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#s3-service-amazon-s3-and-s3-compatible-apis). Then setup the attachments on your model.

```
class Kitteh < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo
end
```

With ActiveStorage you can [directly attach files to records](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects) by passing an IO object:

```
photos = Rails.root.join('path/to/the/images', '*.{jpg,gif,png}')
100.times do |n|
  path = photos.sample
  File.open(path) do |file|
    Kitteh.new(name: "Kitteh #{n}") do |k|
      k.photo.attach(
        io: file,
        filename: path.basename 
      )
    end.save!
  end
end
```

This example creates 100 records with a random image selected from a directory on your hard drive and will upload it to the storage you have configured.